# Retrieve Logcat data through native (C) code

Tags: android, shell, native

I was wondering if there is any way to access the logcat logging data from native code ?
Also if someone knows what kind of shell can be accessed on the native linux system directly on the device itself (so NOT by starting a shell through adb on a client pc !!!) ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can either read the raw data fom /dev/log/main or you can run the built-in shell command logcat and pipe the result to a file descriptor as usual. The logcat command is usually preferably because then the printout is easier to filter and format.

As for the built-in shell, it is called toolbox and the source can be found in the Android open source project. The shell is rather similar to bash. Toolbox contains lots more functionality than just a shell. It is very similar to Busybox, but released under another license.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it up using a log tag in your source file and then include the library as so:

```
#define LOG_TAG "some.unique.identifier" //I usually use the class name
#include <utils/Log.h>
```

Then in the Android.mk file you will need to add the `liblog` library dependency to your `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES`.

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += liblog
```

Also, take note that `logcat` looks for the `LOG_TAG` definition to include as part of the tagging so it makes searching for your logs easier. Then you can log as such:

```
int my_int = 0;
ALOGI("some logs.... print my int: %d", my_int);
```

`ALOGI` is for info, you can also use `ALOGE`, `ALOGD`, `ALOGV` and `ALOGW` for error, debug, verbose and warning logging, respectively.

`ALOG*` is analogous to printf. I interchange them at times if I need to debug on different platforms, say Linux.

Comment: His question was how to READ logcat.